# Is 'Almost nothing did she know about engineering' correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I just wonder whether the sentence, 'She knew almost nothing about engineeering.', could be translated 'Almost nothing did she know about engineering'.
 Someone told me that the sentence should be translated 'Almost nothing about engineering did she know', but i think both sentences could be possible. That's because 'about engineering' is just adverb.

Is 'Almost nothing did she know about engineering' correct?

Comment: Possible, yes, but the typical way of saying this would be as in your first version (She knew...).  Have you read "Green Eggs and Ham" by Dr. Seuss?  (*I am Sam.  Sam I am.*)  Sometimes flipping the word order makes sense....

Comment: The usual reason for inverting sentence structure is to put familiar information first, so as to connect back to previous sentences. Doing this makes your prose flow much better. For your sentence, I can't imagine any good reason for putting "Almost nothing" first. And if you don't have a good reason, you should stick to normal sentence structure.

Comment: To answer the actual question, all these sentences are grammatically correct.

Comment: All three are grammatically correct, but the latter two are very un-idiomatic.

Comment: Says Master Yoda

Comment: It's a bit odd to use "about" when inverting, more usual to say "of". For instance Kipling has the line **Much he knew _of_ foaming waters - not so much _of_ farming land** in his poem [The Land](http://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/poems_land.htm). It's an archaic form but it is correct when "of" is used. Your example should be **Almost nothing did she know _of_ engineering** if you insist on inverting.

Comment: Or "Of engineering, almost nothing did she know".

Comment: This *'She knew almost nothing about engineeering.', could be translated 'Almost nothing did she know about engineering'.* depends entirely on what you mean by "*translated*" - It ***could*** be... but it never ***would*** be, because idiomatic syntax would preclude it being used in a practical form - perhaps other than in a comic poem in the style of Edward Lear.

Answer (score 2):

> Almost nothing did she know about engineering

This ordering is not "normal", but is valid syntax and semantics, and it might very well be used in, eg, a story where the ordering helped to emphasize "almost nothing".  Especially if followed by something like "... but she did know quite a lot about marketing".

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the first sentence. The second two sentences sound stilted, to be sure. They also remind me of [Yoda-speak](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=What%20is%20Yoda-speak%3F#kpvalbx=_fFiRXdrKD4eq_Qap8L2QDQ45).

Comment: Then all 3 sentences could be proper?

Comment: They are all _understandable_, but your two versions sound totally unnatural. Why do you want to 'translate' a normal sentence into mock-archaic language?

Comment: @KateBunting: I think you meant to post your comment to the OP's question, yes? Don, rhetorician

Comment: @rhetorician It was meant as a reply to the OP's question whether 'all three sentences could be proper'.

Comment: @KateBunting: What fooled me was the absence of "at MNL" before your comment. No problem.